# Type-safe error handling without 3rd party libraries

Tags: typescript, error-handling, try-catch

I understand that the reason why typesafe error handling is not a thing in ts is because we are missing the `throws` clause from functions. So because of this whenever I do this:

```
function mighThrow(input: number): void {
  if (input === 1) {
    throw new TypeError('cannot be one')
  } else if(input === 2) {
    throw new SyntaxError('invalid syntax: 2')
  }
  console.log('all good', input)
}
```

I can't catch the errors with accurate typing:

```
try {
  mighThrow(1)
} catch(e) {
  // e is any, even though it could be TypeError | SyntaxError
}
```

The issue is the same with `Promise`s, the catcher functions argument is hardcoded `any`:

```
interface Promise<T> {
  then<TResult1 = T, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: ((value: T) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>) | undefined | null, onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<TResult2>) | undefined | null): Promise<TResult1 | TResult2>;
  catch<TResult = never>(onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult | PromiseLike<TResult>) | undefined | null): Promise<T | TResult>;
}
```

The argument of `catch` is any.

So **my question is** how can I get around this? If I'm a library author, is there a typesafe way to help users figure out what exactly are they catching? I'm aware of solutions like adding an `Either` type and calling it a day, but this enforces handling the error on the spot, which just turns the code into something similar to as if the language would have checked exceptions.

Comment: Relevant TypeScript issues: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13219 and https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5413.

Comment: @JoeClay those where the issues that inspired this question, thanks for linking them!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there's currently [no `throws` in TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13219), any suggestion is going to look like a workaround.  You're looking for a solution that doesn't result in any overhead for the user who wants to ignore errors, but which allows the users who do want to catch errors to get stronger types for the errors.

How about something like this (which requires TS3.1 and up to work):

```
function mighThrow(input: number): void {
  if (input === 1) {
    throw new TypeError('cannot be one')
  } else if (input === 2) {
    throw new SyntaxError('invalid syntax: 2')
  }
  console.log('all good', input);
}
mighThrow.throws = undefined! as TypeError | SyntaxError;
```

Here we have used a [function property declaration](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#properties-declarations-on-functions) to declare a phantom property called `throws`.  A phantom property is one which doesn't really exist at runtime, but the compiler thinks it does, so the compiler maintains extra type information.  In this case, `undefined! as TypeError | SyntaxError` is just `undefined` at runtime, but the compiler thinks `mighThrow` has a `throws` property of type `TypeError | SyntaxError`.

Now when people want to catch errors, they can use a helper function:

```
type ThrowsType<T> = T extends { throws: infer E } ? E : unknown;
const asTypedError = <FS extends Function[]>(e: any, ...f: FS): ThrowsType<FS[number]> => e;
```

like this:

```
try {
  const x = mighThrow(123);
} catch (err) {
  const typedErr = asTypedError(mighThrow, err);
  // typedErr is now TypeError | SyntaxError
  if (typedErr instanceof TypeError) {
    typedErr; // TypeError
  } else {
    typedErr; // SyntaxError
  }       
}
```

---

It's not perfect by any means.  It requires the error catcher to keep track of which functions were called themselves.  A try-catch block that surrounds multiple functions would need to pass in all those functions to `asTypedError()`:

```
declare const alsoMightThrow: { throws: URIError } & ((input: string) => number);
try {
  const x = mighThrow(alsoMightThrow("hey"));
} catch (err) {     
  const typedErr = asTypedError(err, mighThrow, alsoMightThrow); // 
  // typedErr: TypeError | SyntaxError | URIError
}
```

And nothing actually *guarantees* that the caught error is of the type(s) declared in the `throws` property... it's up to the library maintainer to get that right (which is hard because so many things can throw a `TypeError` at runtime).  Conversely, most functions will not have such a `throws` property, so there's not a lot of incentive for the average developer to use this type of error catching.  If someone puts a non-`throws` function there, `asTypedError` will output an [`unknown`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#new-unknown-top-type) error, which is hardly more useful than `any`. You'd have to educate library users how to use this thing, at which point it could be easier just to [document](http://usejsdoc.org/) the heck out of your function and error catchers can do their own `instanceof` checks to narrow from `any`.  It's a workaround for a missing language feature, and it looks like it.  ‍♀️

---

Oh well, hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: I love asking these questions because I learn something new about ts every time (didn't know that you can declare function props)! The idea looks like a pretty nice workaround!